# Monotouch bindings make my apps size huge

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm using Monotouch to create iOS apps. 
I've created bindings for ChartBoost, RevMob and others.

The problem that I'm having is that the final app has a size of about 20MB. This is way too much for such a simple game app.

I've checked the main app projects dll and it is only about 500KB large. But the binding dlls are altogether about 19MB.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I've already done the following things but with no luck:
- Link native SDKs only
- Use only ARMV7
- Use LLVM
- Added LinkerSafe attribute to my Binding projects.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What about linking everything (not just sdks)? Did that help?

Comment: It reduces the size a bit but I don't think it's worth the hassle as my app crashes when doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your settings sounds sane - but there not many details in your question that we can use to help you. If you use several **native** libraries then it's not surprising to get large applications.

Note that **Link native SDKs only** does not exists. It's **Link SDK assemblies only** and it applies only to managed assemblies (not native). Still **managed** linking is very important as it will allow further optimizations to be possible.

When you add `[LinkerSafe]` in your binding project then the unused code will be removed (even if **Link SDK** is used). It also does quite a bit of optimizations on the generated binding code (making it smaller and faster). Make sure (compare before and after sizes) that the bindings assemblies includes the attribute.

You might want to use **Link all assemblies** to get the maximum savings. Again compare the before (link sdk) and after (link all) to see what were the gains (you might have to `[Preserve]` some of your code to make this work, e.g. if you use reflection).

There is a **very** new feature, [`SmartLink`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.LinkWithAttribute.SmartLink), which remove the `--force_load` requirement that will make it easier to remove native code (e.g. from **most** native libraries). It's hard to predict savings (not enough data) but a lot of binding samples (on github) saved between 250KB to 400KB.

Note: I'll update my answer once the video of my Evolve talk (about build optimizations) is available online. In the mean time there's quite a few [older blog post](https://gist.github.com/spouliot/e2975168b139b5b197e1) I did (and other documents) that can help you optimize the size of your applications.

Comment: Thank you, you have mentioned some really interesting things. I'm not sure but where do I have to add [Preserve] and SmartLink?  
A different question: Could it be a problem HOW I add the bindings to my project? I haven't found a right way to do it so far but ATM I'm adding the binding projects via "Add existing project..." to my Xamarin project and add project references in my main app project.

Comment: This has made me think that there must be some way to reduce the app size: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/63zzgPZqlpk.

Comment: About your link... Xamarin.iOS already does the same. IOW if you build for ARMv7 then only the ARMv7 parts of the static library (you use) will be added to your application (so the `libXXX.a` size can be misleading). You can verify this using the `file`, `lipo` and `nm` tools. They will all report (differently) which architecture your application provides code for.

Comment: `SmartLink` is a boolean property you can set on your `[LinkWith]` attributes (there's normally one per binding). `[Preserve]` should be added on the code you want to ensure the linker won't remove (even if it does not seems to be used, e.g. reflection). An alternative is to use an XML file (e.g. if you do not have the source code). See the links I provided in my answer. The way you add the bindings (e.g. a reference to the .dll or to the binding project) should **not** affect the size of your application. OTOH other settings (like Debug vs Release, LLVM...) will affect the app size.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. SmartLink won't work for me, whenever I try to add it I get an error "'MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.LinkWithAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'SmartLink' (CS 0117)".

Comment: Like I said `SmartLink` is **very** new feature - it might only be available in the next release of Xamarin.iOS (in testing, or in the betas). I was surprised to find it available in the documentation, but it might have been updated for the beta or just too early.